# Highcharts - parameter of a custom technical indicator displayed as a drop-down menu

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a custom technical indicator in highcharts. I need to enter a parameter whose values ​​must belong to set ('sma','rma','ema','wma'), so I was thinking of using a dropdown menu.

I would like a result like this:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p0Ik.png)

Answer (score 0):

For such a dropdown menu, you can simply use the HTML select tag to which you will add the logic of changing the indicators.

```js
document.getElementById('indicators').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  const series = chart.get('indicator');

  if (series) {
    series.remove(false);
    chart.addSeries({
      id: 'indicator',
      type: e.target.value,
      linkedTo: 'main',
      yAxis: 1,
      color: 'green'
    });
  }
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/khn670b2/ 
**Docs**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/custom-technical-indicators

Comment: Sorry,  I realized that I expressed badly.
I need a dropdown-menu inside of custom technical indicator parameters.
I don't want an external menu, but parameter of the indicator shown as a dropdown menu.
Thanks